# CSS background-image property not loading

Tags: image, css

I am working on a website, and am currently on the homepage. I had a previously-written CSS header, and wanted to substitute an image for the background of the header `<div>` instead of a solid color, as in the previous design. I have a header image, in the `img/header.jpg` directory. I am loading the background image using the `background-image` property like so:

```
background-image: url(img/header.jpg)
```

The problem is, it does not load the image, the background is just silver (which is what the background of the `<body>` is set to).
Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong here? (the browser I am testing it in is IE8, if that might have anything to do with it :)

Comment: Post the rest of your CSS. The relevant HTML would help too.

Comment: @Andrew Charlton yes, my div has a height and width set, the problem was just that my path wasn't configured right for where the file was.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If this is in a separate CSS file note that urls should be relative to the location of this CSS file. So for example if your CSS file is located in `~/styles/main.css` the rule should be:

```
background-image: url('../img/header.jpg')
```

assuming the image is located in `~/img/header.jpg`.

Comment: @Nate Koppenhaver, I am glad I could help.