# Image background not loading with CSS

Tags: html, css

Okay I can't comment on any other questions that's why I am posting a new question.

I've tried all solutions suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21374534/css-background-image-not-loading) answer, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862887/css-background-image-property-not-loading.) as well.

```css
#head {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: roboto;
}

body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

.parallax {

    background-image: url('.../pics/parallax.jpg');

    height: 100%; 

    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
  <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/text.css">
    <script src="scripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.animate-color.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/custom_scripts.js"></script>
    <title>Yadullah.me</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1 id="head"> Hi there!</h1>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Pretty simple right? But for some reason the background image just refuses to show up.
I have tried with my CSS, HTML, and image in the same folder with no success. Tried in different sub-directories, no success.

I have checked file name, extension and all of that stuff. Tried without quotes and what not. Tried different images even. Tried removing all other CSS files as well, nothing works.

Comment: looks like one dot is too many in the path to image ....

Comment: To elaborate on GCyrillus's comment, `url('.../pics/parallax.jpg');` should be `url('../pics/parallax.jpg');`

Comment: @Santi unfortunately, that didn't work either

Comment: @YaddyVirus Tell us a bit more about your file structure. Where is your CSS file in relation to the image you're trying to retrieve?

Comment: @Santi I have a folder on my f: drive by the name of Yadullah.me, that folder has 3 sub folders namely, css, scripts and pics. The html is in the root folder (i.e Yadullah.me folder)

Comment: And I assume that the `css` is in the `css` folder. When you go to console, are you getting any errors? Any 404's?

Comment: @Santi no not at all. The CSS works just fine except for this error.

Answer (score 3):

You have a few too many stops in your style property. Your css should look like this:

```
.parallax {
    background-image: url('../pics/parallax.jpg');
    ...
}
```

Comment: Just to rule out the obvious, what is the name of your css file? And what folder is it located in?

Comment: it is located in a folder named css. The file's name is text.css

Answer (score 0):

```
#head {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: roboto;
}

body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

.parallax {

    background-image: url('.../pics/parallax.jpg'); // In Here try put absolute URL or change .../ in ../

    height: 100%; 
width:100%; //and try add width
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try add base tag for example like this 

<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <base href="http://YourSite.com/"> 
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/text.css">
    <script src="scripts/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.animate-color.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/custom_scripts.js"></script>
    <title>Yadullah.me</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1 id="head"> Hi there!</h1>

    </body>
    </html>
```